# cannot remove a tuple from list of tuples using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples, and I want to remove an element from this list. I don't want to use the `remove()` method because the list is not unique and I want to remove all elements that match a given tuple.

So, why doesn't the code below remove the  `(21, 187)` element?

```
edgeList = [(1, 2), (3, 75), (21, 187), (2, 6)]
edgeList = [(e1, e2) for e1, e2 in edgeList if (e1 != 21 & e2 != 187)]
print(edgeList)
```

The code above will print:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 75), (21, 187), (2, 6)]
```

Why is the tuple `(21, 187)` still there?

Answer (score 4):

You're using the bit operator `&`, you want to use `and`:

```
edgeList = [(e1,e2) for e1,e2 in edgeList if (e1!=21 and e2!=187)]
```

The problem is that `&` has a different precedence than `and`, so you end up doing `e1 != (21 & e2) != 187`

Comment: Thanks. One of the pitfalls of learning too many languages at the same time.. haha. you forget which one had which. I appreciate the fast response.

Answer (score 4):

[Francisco's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407203/1391671) correctly points out that your problem arises because comparisons (e.g. `!=`) have lower precedence than bitwise boolean operators (e.g. `&`), but higher precedence than logical boolean operators (e.g. `and`). You could also avoid the issue entirely by doing something like

```
[e for e in edgeList if e != (21, 187)]
```

Tuples in python compare equal if all their elements compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&` if you enclose each inequality check in parentheses:
`edgeList = [(e1,e2) for e1,e2 in edgeList if ((e1!=21) & (e2!=187))]`